# Cannot use Local Variable 'pagefrom' before it is declared in C# Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Purpose of this code is to : - It will find the "Ending balance" word in an .pdf file and it will split / extract the pages.

'__________________________________________
// This example page extraction by found keyword.

```
using System;
using Bytescout.PDFExtractor;

namespace SplittingExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string inputFile = @"C:\Users\trajan3\Desktop\Pdf Splitting Test\aa.pdf";
            int pagefrom = 1 + 0;

        // (!) page number in ExtractPage() is 1-based
        // Create Bytescout.PDFExtractor.TextExtractor instance
        TextExtractor extractor = new TextExtractor();
        extractor.RegistrationName = "demo";
        extractor.RegistrationKey = "demo";
        string searchString = "Ending Balance";


        // Load sample PDF document
        extractor.LoadDocumentFromFile(inputFile);

        int pageCount = extractor.GetPageCount();

        // Search each page for a keyword 
        for (int i = 0; i < pageCount; i++)
        {

            if (extractor.Find(i, searchString, false))
            {
                // Extract page
                using (DocumentSplitter splitter = new DocumentSplitter("demo", "demo"))
                {
                    splitter.OptimizeSplittedDocuments = true;

                    int pageNumber = i + 1;  // (!) page number in ExtractPage() is 1-based


                    string outputFile = @".\page" + pageNumber + ".pdf";
                    splitter.ExtractPageRange(inputFile, outputFile, pagefrom, pageNumber);

                    Console.WriteLine("Extracted page " + **pagefrom** + " to " + pageNumber + " to file \"" + outputFile + "\"");
                    int **pagefrom** = i + **pagefrom**;  // (!) page number in ExtractPage() is 1-based

                }
            }


        } 
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key...");
        Console.ReadKey();          
    }
}
```

}

But for "pagefrom' variable is underlying with red colour stating  cannot use local variable 'pagefrom' before it is declared. Can someone please help me on this.

Comment: We can't really help you when we don't know what you're trying to achieve. When you refer to `pagefrom` in the two lines before it's declared, what would you *expect* it to do?

Comment: The error message is confusing but basically you're trying to declare two separate variables in nested scopes with the same name `int pagefrom = 1 + 0;` at the top and `int **pagefrom** = i + **pagefrom**;` towards the bottom. Don't do this.

Comment: I want to do the Iterate. At the top i want to set it as : - int pagefrom = 1

Comment: and in below if conditions met : then it has to iterate : pagefrom + pageto

Comment: What is purpose of `int pagefrom = 1 + 0;`, why not only `int pagefrom = 1`?

Comment: Replace 'int **pagefrom** = i + **pagefrom**; ' by 'pagefrom += i'

Comment: Hi Thank you so much now it's working awesome.

Comment: any updates pls